# Circular permutations with indistinguishable objects

Tags: combinatorics

Given n distinct objects, there are $n!$ permutations of the objects and $n!/n$ "circular permutations" of the objects (orientation of the circle matters, but there is no starting point, so $1234$ and $2341$ are the same, but $4321$ is different).

Given $n$ objects of $k$ types (where the objects within each type are indistinguishable), $r_i$ of the $i^{th}$ type, there are

\begin{equation*}
\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_k!}
\end{equation*}

permutations.  How many circular permutations are there of such a set?

Comment: BTW, the answer is *not* [$\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_k!}$](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7Bn%21%7D%7Br_1%21r_2%21%5Ccdots%20r_k%21%7D).

Comment: Could you go into the motivation behind the problem?

Comment: A trivial observation: For string S, concatenate with itself infinite many times to get a infinite string. Find the period of this infinite string. The period shows how many strings you can generate from string S and considered different permutations.

Comment: Period of $p$ is not feasible unless $p$ is divisible by $\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{r_i}{\gcd(r_1, r_2, r_3....,r_k)}$.

Comment: @Kenny: Why not? Seems perfectly sensible to me.

Comment: @Noldorin: Counter example, two 1's.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wrote a series of blog posts which explains how to solve questions like this; the relevant one is [here](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/gila-v-the-polya-enumeration-theorem-and-applications/).  The generating function you want is

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} (x_1^{n/d} + ... + x_k^{n/d})^d \varphi \left( \frac{n}{d} \right)$$

where the coefficient of $x_1^{r_1} ... x_k^{r_k}$ is the number you want.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is best solved with Pólya's enumeration theorem, which follows from Burnside's lemma.  See the first section of [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem).

Comment: Okay, I can see how the first section of the Wikipedia article appears to talk about this problem as the necklace problem, but can't quite get a handle on how to use it.  How would one apply Pólya's enumeration theorem to necklaces made with, say, 3 red beads and 5 blue beads?

Answer (score 0):

A closed-form solution to this problem is

$$\frac{1}{n}\,\sum_{d\mid\gcd(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_k)}\,\phi(d)\,\binom{n/d}{r_1/d,r_2/d,\ldots,r_k/d}$$

where $\phi(d)$ is the Euler's totient function.

More details and examples are provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4791405/1231520)