# Number of Necklace/Bracelets With Fixed Number of Beads

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular permutations with indistinguishable objects](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600/circular-permutations-with-indistinguishable-objects)

We can compute the total number of k-ary necklaces/bracelets of length n using the Euler totient function:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29

Apparently there is a formula for the number of k-ary necklaces/bracelets when the number of beads for each color is fixed.

For example, the number of necklaces/bracelets of length 5, made up of three colors (red, green, blue), with 2 red beads, 2 green beads, and 1 blue bead. etc.

Can anyone provide the formula or a reference?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate (asked and answered): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600/circular-permutations-with-indistinguishable-objects/825#825

Comment: Thanks Qiaochu. Should this question be closed since it's a duplicate?