# How many ways to make a bracelet with $n$ white balls and $m$ black balls?

Tags: combinatorics

Okay so I have $n$ black ball and $m$ white balls. How many bracelets can I make using all the balls? At first I thought there are $(n+m-1)!$ if all the balls were different. So we can divide into groups of $n!\cdot m!$ that look the same if you permute the black balls between them and also for the white balls.

However if I had $6$ white balls and $2$ black this would yield $3.5$ so clearly this can't be correct. How can I count this?

Is there a generalized version form for $k$ colors?

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600/circular-permutations-with-indistinguishable-objects/825#825

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution to this is given by Pólya's theory of counting. The result is quite complex, no simple formula results except for very special cases.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a straight line, it is $\frac {(n+m)!}{n!m!}={n+m \choose n}$ because you choose the positions for the white balls and the black ones follow.  When you make a bracelet, naively you would divide by $n+m$ for the rotations, giving exactly the formula you state:  $\frac {(n+m-1)!}{n!m!}$  The problem comes from patterns that can be rotated to give the same necklace in more than one way.  So for $n=4,m=2$ the ${6 \choose 2}=15$linear strings are

$BBBBWW,BBBWBW,BBWBBW,BWBBBW,WBBBBW,\\BBBWWB,BBWBWB,BWBBWB,WBBBWB,BBWWBB,\\BWBWBB,WBBWBB,BWWBBB,WBWBBB,WWBBBB$

Now when we make necklaces of them, we get $BBBBWW,BBBWBW,BBWBBW$, where the first two account for six of the fifteen, but the last only accounts for three.

Comment: Oh, I see, but how can we count them then?