# How many possible ways are there to split 200 coins between three different baskets?

Tags: combinatorics

so my answer is (202 choose 2)

But if baskets were identical? 
Should we first choose a basket where to put some coins?

Comment: If the baskets are identical, you have to break into cases: 1) Two baskets have the same number of coins 2) All baskets have a different number of coins.

Comment: Are the coins indistinguishable?

Comment: Refer to Stefen's answer in the question.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2619042/circular-permutations-with-alike-objects.          I know the question is different but on careful reading you will understand that the method to solve is very similar

Comment: 202 choose 2 counts the ways to split 200 indistinguishable coins into 3 baskets, so it looks like coins are indistinguishable.

Comment: The number of placements of n indistinguishable objects into x indistinguishable baskets is counted by the [integer partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#case_fnx) of n into $\leq$ x parts.